# How to poll a remote directory for new files using kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message-queue, rsync

I have a folder on remote location and some other process keeps putting files in it.

I am writing an application to download each new file and process it.

For now I am downloading files with `rsync` that has been created in last hour and process it.

But I need a solution where I want to put name of new file to be put onto a queue and then my consumer will take names from queue, download the file and process.

In this solution I can run multiple producers which will poll only on kafka queue.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using Kafka Connect? There are connectors that do exactly what you need: watch directory for a new files and put their content record by record directly to the Kafka. For example: https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir.

Or a simpler connector that put only new/modified files metadata: https://github.com/DataReply/kafka-connect-directory-source